# Unable to boot up Debian from external SSD on T430 but works on old Acer notebook

Tags: debian, boot, external-hdd

I synced my Debian bullseye (Bios install) on an external SSD with rsync.

```
fdisk -l /dev/sdc
Festplatte /dev/sdc: 476,94 GiB, 512110190592 Bytes, 1000215216 Sektoren
Festplattenmodell: Portable SSD    
Einheiten: Sektoren von 1 * 512 = 512 Bytes
Sektorgröße (logisch/physikalisch): 512 Bytes / 4096 Bytes
E/A-Größe (minimal/optimal): 4096 Bytes / 4096 Bytes
Festplattenbezeichnungstyp: dos
Festplattenbezeichner: 0xbd48852c

Gerät      Boot    Anfang      Ende  Sektoren Größe Kn Typ
/dev/sdc1            2048  83888127  83886080   40G 83 Linux
/dev/sdc2        83888128 104859647  20971520   10G 82 Linux Swap / Solaris
/dev/sdc3       104859648 838862847 734003200  350G  5 Erweiterte
/dev/sdc5       104861696 838862847 734001152  350G 83 Linux
```

It is connected through

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 152d:0579 JMicron Technology Corp. / JMicron USA Technology Corp. Portable SSD
```

Note I changed UUID in the systemfiles (like /etc/fstab)
I chroot'ed into the system and reconfigured grub-pc so it installs in the MBR from the external SSD.

I tried to boot up from UEFI boot menu (legacy only configured) I tried to start from grub menu from "old Debian bullseye" I changed some settings in UEFI related to USB and security. Nothing worked.

```
unable to get C/H/S you have to load the kernel first #from fuzzy memory
```

I was so desperate I tried it on my broken old Acer notebook and it boots up without error.

Differences of related hardware:

T430:
has UEFI and USB 3.0 ports

Acer:
has BIOS and only USB 2.0 ports

Comment: do you get grub cmd line like `grub >`?

Comment: Nope in both cases i get thrown back to boot menu (uefi boot order menu or when i try to boot from internal grub menu back to grub menu).

Comment: can you press '**e**' to edit the boot command or '**c**' to get to the shell **in grub menu**?

Comment: I finally got it to boot over internal grub after reset uefi menu to default.  Maybe  a problem with jmicron chip my external focal does also only boot over internal jammy grub is also connected over a jmicron bridge.

Comment: okay it is this jmicron chips stuff. I found an older buster install on usb flash drive is booting from uefi bootmenu directly.

Comment: could you now write an answer to the question yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally make it work. I wrote a quirk for this drive before connecting (i saw uas errors)

```
options usb-storage quirks=152d:0579:u
```

I started over with formating my both ext4 linux filesystem without the feature

```
metadata_csum
```

Changed all relevant UUID's (fstab/grub.cfg) from my original debian and boot it up over grub in old debian and reconfigured grub-pc.

Then it was starting. But I have no idea why it wasn't starting in the first place on my thinkpad (maybe uefi firmware related?).